# How do i show users data in an array in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I want to show the user's data in Array in laravel with the following query.

```
public static function fetchRelatedSnippets($slug){  
  $query = DB::select("SELECT s2.name,s2.slug,s2.image,s2.counter_views,s2.user_id,user.picture,user.username,user.name as user_name FROM snippets s1 INNER JOIN snippettags st1 ON st1.snippet_id = s1.id INNER JOIN snippettags st2 ON st2.tag_id = st1.tag_id AND st2.snippet_id != st1.snippet_id INNER JOIN snippets s2 ON s2.id = st2.snippet_id INNER JOIN users user ON user.id = s2.user_id WHERE s1.slug = '$slug' GROUP BY s2.id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, SUM(st1.priority) ASC LIMIT 18");
  
  return $query;
}
```

With the above query, I am getting the following result

```
      {
        "name": "Multi step form wizard",
        "slug": "multi-step-form-wizard",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/ewrrwer.png",
        "counter_views": 195363,
        "user_id": "43",
        "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mDrfDzN8LO7D406AeQdeqY- 
        6ddGsTnF2ja4OObF2A",
        "username": "john-doe-12121",
        "user_name": "John Doe"
    },
```

But I want to follow result

```
{
        "name": "Multi step form wizard",
        "slug": "multi-step-form-wizard",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/343243.png",
        "counter_views": 195363,
        user:{
           "user_id": "43",
           "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mDrfDzN8LO7D",
           "username": "john-doe-212121",
           "user_name": "John Doe"
        }

    },
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier when using Eloquent models instead of raw queries and the DB class. Also, you are using variables directly in your query string, that means you are open to sql injection.

Comment: Read in your results, reformat to the desired format, output desired format

Comment: You could easily achieve this using the relationships of Laravel